# Do not draw line on condition in ChartJS line chart

Tags: javascript, dom, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I would like not draw line between two dots when a condition is triggered.

I'm using chartjs a time line graph.

My condition is not to draw line when `y` value **decreases** so in this example when it passes from 7 to 1

```
{x:3.5*3600, y:7},
Do not draw line between these two points
{x:4*3600, y:1},
```

Is it possible to do with chartjs line time graph ?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var config = {
  "options": {
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [
            {
              "type": 'time',
              "time": {
                "unit": 'minute',
                "unitStepSize": 60,

              },
              "distribution": 'linear',
              "bounds": 'ticks',
              "ticks": {
                "source": 'auto',
                "autoSkip": true,
                "stepSize": 10
              }
            }
          ],
    },
  },
  "data": {
   "labels": ['2016-04-18T00:00:00Z', '2016-04-18T23:59:00Z'],
    "datasets": [
    {
      "label": "line",
      "type": "line",
      "backgroundColor": "#00b",
      "borderColor": "#00b",
      //"yAxisID": "axis4",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "fill": false,
      "data": [
{x:"2016-04-18T01:00:00Z", y:1},
{x:"2016-04-18T04:00:00Z", y:2},
{x:"2016-04-18T06:00:00Z", y:3},
{x:"2016-04-18T08:00:00Z", y:7},
{x:"2016-04-18T10:00:00Z", y:1},
{x:"2016-04-18T14:00:00Z", y:3},

]
    },
    ]
  },

};
var myBarChart = Chart.Line(canvas, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

**Update**
I have tried to add `{x:null,y:null}` or `null` between the two items but I get this error

```
Error: 0 and 1461023970000 are too far apart with stepSize of 60 minute
```

In my options I have :

```
"data": [
  {x:"2016-04-18T01:00:00Z", y:1},
  {x:"2016-04-18T04:00:00Z", y:2},
  {x:"2016-04-18T06:00:00Z", y:3},
  {x:"2016-04-18T08:00:00Z", y:7},
  {x:null,y:null},
  {x:"2016-04-18T10:00:00Z", y:1},
  {x:"2016-04-18T14:00:00Z", y:3},
]
```

...

```
xAxes: [
    {
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'minute',
        unitStepSize: 60,
        parser: function(date) {
          return moment(date).toLocaleString();
        }
      },
      distribution: 'linear',
      bounds: 'ticks',
      ticks: {
        source: 'auto',
        autoSkip: true,
        stepSize: 10
      }
    }
  ],
```

It's like chartjs considering null to be a big value

Comment: I have Updated my example code , now I get the same error that I mentionned when I add  `{x:null,y:null}` to the code example

Comment: Your empty point must be timestamped: `{x:"2016-04-18T08:00:01Z", y:null}`. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t1s54gdh/

Comment: Perfect, You can post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @JérémieL Beat me by ten minutes. Add an answer so the question can be closed and you earn your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set y as null while still defining the x co-ordinate.

```
"data": [
  {x:"2016-04-18T01:00:00Z", y:1},
  {x:"2016-04-18T04:00:00Z", y:2},
  {x:"2016-04-18T06:00:00Z", y:3},
  {x:"2016-04-18T08:00:00Z", y:7},
  {x:"2016-04-18T08:00:01Z", y:null},
  {x:"2016-04-18T10:00:00Z", y:1},
  {x:"2016-04-18T14:00:00Z", y:3},
]
```

Comment: You could at least give @JérémieL credit if you post his answer to get the accepted answer AND the bounty...

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the Chart.js documentation (see [`spanGaps`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling)), if `spanGaps` is falsy (as default), points with `NaN` data will create a break in the line.

So, the trick is to insert an empty point, as you tried to do. This empty point must be timestamped, with a timestamp between the two points defining the "hole" in the line:

```js
"data": [
  {x:"2016-04-18T01:00:00Z", y:1},
  {x:"2016-04-18T04:00:00Z", y:2},
  {x:"2016-04-18T06:00:00Z", y:3},
  {x:"2016-04-18T08:00:00Z", y:7},
  {x:"2016-04-18T08:00:00Z", y:null}, // or NaN
  {x:"2016-04-18T10:00:00Z", y:1},
  {x:"2016-04-18T14:00:00Z", y:3},
]
```

See this fiddle as example: https://jsfiddle.net/t1s54gdh/

Comment: I'm trying to apply this to another example with colorize segments separately it's seems not working , Here an example https://codepen.io/infofou/pen/yLLmYGj

Comment: Remove the filter on points in order to let Chart.js apply the  `spanGaps`: https://codepen.io/jledentu/pen/wvvVMgp